# Facebook FriendPicker

Tags: facebook, drawable

hi im having trouble with the friendpicker... i cannt get the drawable.action_people since i dont have it.. but on the Facebook SDK theres not an existing file with that name... please help me!!!... heres my code

private class PeopleListElement extends BaseListElement {

```
    public PeopleListElement(int requestCode) {
        super(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_people),
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.action_people),
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.action_people_default),
                requestCode);
    }
```

Comment: i introduce a drawable element on the res file and problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Modify it as follows.

public PeopleListElement(int requestCode) {
            super(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_friends),
                    getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.action_people),`enter code here`
                    null,
                    requestCode);
        }

Make sure that you have the constructor of BaseListElement as follows.
   public BaseListElement(Drawable icon, String text1, String text2, int requestCode) {